# Java -jar command fails with an error "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, jvm, akka

Hi I'm building an application in which we use Akka and Scala. When I use IntelliJ IDE to clean and install my application there are no errors produced for the build. Our next step is to use Jenkins Looper to deploy it on cloud, and that was failing. When that happened we attemtped to debug the issue using java -jar command on the jar file that is produced by the code. When we do that a stack trace error is produced as follows:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/http/scaladsl/server/Directive

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)

        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)

        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)

        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)

        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)

        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

        ... 7 more
```

Can someone help me debug that error? I see that the caused by shows it's unable to find akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive, but I cannot determine what that Exception with "main" is and what to do about it.

Comment: it would be nice if you post the versions of scala on your local machine and on jenkins and the version of akka itself

Comment: My local system when I run scala -version it shows:

Scala code runner version 2.12.4. Java version 1.8.0_131-b11. I don't know how to check the remaining. Sorry I'm a newbie to this. When I vi the build.sbt file I see akkaVersion as 2.5.6.

I don't know if we need to look at Jenkins looper part of this since locally when I do java -jar, it doesn't seem to build so I wonder if jenkins comes into play. Once we fix this exception if the build fails on Jenkins then I can  find out the versions. But I'm very new so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @SergeyShinkarenko

Comment: Could you post your build.sbt? "scala -version" is irrelevant as sbt pulls the scala version specified in build.sbt and uses it instead of the locally installed one. Look for scalaVersion := "<version>" in your build.sbt or in  *.scala  files in project dir. Also make sure that all Scala version dependent jars use %% when you specify them in project dependencies, something like "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpV

Comment: @DenisMakarenko: Inside the pom.xml file I was able to find these versions. <scala.version> 2.12.4 </scala.version> and akka versions are showing up individually for each dependency and they are all showing akka 2.12 version.

Comment: Are you using maven or sbt to build your project? Also try running your program with -verbose:class Java option to see which jars are loaded on runtime

Comment: I did java -verbose:class <myjarname>.jar and it listed out several of the jar's it loaded first, `[Loaded java.text.MessageFormat$Field from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]` like that and then failed with this at the end: `Error: Could not find or load main class <myjarfile>.jar`. Not very useful since it didn't tell us anything new from what we already know right? It just reiterated that cannot find main in that jar file. I am using Maven, and I tried running the jar from within IntelliJ IDE and from terminal (target folder). Same result @Deni

Comment: Are akka and other dependencies in the class path? If you’re not building a fat jar, they all must be available on the target machine for your app to load.

Comment: @DenisMakarenko I pushed this to Git and had one of my friends download the same code, it runs ok in their env. I wonder what is missing in mine especially because half of the code is written by me and it complies ok. But when I import new classes from my other project, and package them correctly and run the jar it fails. How do I check what dependency might be missing if one is? pom.xml is long enough that there are a lot in there, jar is pretty small actually. The application is light as well. Build takes less than a minute. Let me know how to find these dependencies that may be missing.

Comment: @DenisMakarenko It only complains about 2 things, the Main missing which is the exception itself, don't know what that means. And the cause that shows the akka dependency. Don't know what it would be missing about it thou. I have the import and then extends as follows:

`import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives` 
`object <objectname> extends Directives with SprayJsonSupport{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit= {`

Cause shows it has some issue with `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives` in that above stack trace.

Comment: You can try to rule out problems with resolving main by commenting out all the code in this method and printing some message instead

Comment: Based on the error message, it is likely it can’t find akka http module. Have you tried to use Maven dependency plugin to view all the transitive dependencies of your app ? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: @DenisMakarenko, I commented everything out and put hello world in the main. When I used package on the top my build is ok but run fails. This shows that it could be the way I imported the other scala files. Is there an article that I can use for correctly importing multiple files and using them in a package to compile a jar file? If so that'd be a great help. Thanks for all the pointers!

Comment: @DenisMakarenko After removing everything it still appears that the issue is unresolved. If I remove everything and put something as simple as hello world, it complains about Main not found in that package. But with everything there, it complains about that dependency for Scala. I'm not sure how to fix it, can you help? `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive` that's the one it complains about in the exception. I tried Scala various versions, and akka as well.

Comment: Any Suggestions on this?!